# SSH Pseudo-Terminal without option

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis and have to use [OpenTOSCA](http://www.iaas.uni-stuttgart.de/OpenTOSCA/indexE.php). We have a NodeType that connects to a Ubuntu 14.04 VM via SSH. I want to start a program in the background, which is not supplied as a Linux service. So I have to use something like

```
npm start &
```

or

```
screen -m -d npm start
```

But when I do this, the deployment doesn't start the application. I've found out, that the problem is that no terminal is normally allocated when I execute a script via SSH. I was wondering if it is possible to allocate a terminal in the script, so that I don't have to change the implementation of the NodeType?

Comment: There is `-t` switch.

Comment: @Jakuje but for using the -t switch, I'd have to change the NodeType implementation. I'd prefer I could do this in there script itself.

Comment: The `-t` switch to `ssh`.

Comment: @Jakuje the NodeType establishes the connection to the VM, so the NodeType uses SSH.

Comment: ok. You can specify that also in the `ssh_config` using `RequestTTY`, if you use OpenSSH.

Comment: @Jakuje OK, that is more helpful xD

Comment: @Jakuje ok, not as helpful as I first thought... I only have access to the SSH-Server, not the client.

Comment: There is no way to force it on the server.